# Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, transactions, rust

i am trying to pay for a transaction to post a title to my anchor code, but we get the error Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit, which is strange since i do have 4 sol on the author.publicKey so it should have enough sol to pay for the transaction. this is my react code

```
import * as Web3 from '@solana/web3.js';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const PROGRAM_ID = new Web3.PublicKey("ChT1B39WKLS8qUrkLvFDXMhEJ4F1XZzwUNHUt4AU9aVa")
const PROGRAM_DATA_PUBLIC_KEY = new Web3.PublicKey("Ah9K7dQ8EHaZqcAsgBW8w37yN2eAy3koFmUn4x3CJtod")


const TWEET_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'tweet_account.json';
const author_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'author_account.json';
async function pingProgram(
  connection: Web3.Connection,
  tweet: Web3.Keypair,
  author: Web3.Keypair
) {
  const transaction = new Web3.Transaction();
  // console.log(tweet.publicKey.toString());
  const tweetTitle = "My first tweet!";
  const instruction = new Web3.TransactionInstruction({
    keys: [
      { pubkey: tweet.publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
      { pubkey: author.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: false },
      { pubkey: PROGRAM_DATA_PUBLIC_KEY, isSigner: false, isWritable: false },
    ],
    programId: PROGRAM_ID,
  });
  
  const authorSecret = author.secretKey
  transaction.add(instruction);
  
  const transactionSignature = await Web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [author], // add author as payer to signers
    { commitment: 'singleGossip', preflightCommitment: 'singleGossip' },
  );

  console.log(
    `Transaction https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=testnet`
  );
}



async function main() {
  const connection = new Web3.Connection(Web3.clusterApiUrl('testnet'));
  // const signer = await Web3.Keypair.generate();
  let author;
  if (!process.env.PRIVATE_KEY) {
    console.log('Generating new keypair');
    author = Web3.Keypair.generate();
    fs.writeFileSync('.env', `PRIVATE_KEY=[${author.secretKey.toString()}]`);
  } else {
    console.log('Using existing keypair');
    const privateKeyArray = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.split(',').map(s => parseInt(s));
    const privateKeyUint8Array = new Uint8Array(privateKeyArray);
    author = new Web3.Keypair({ publicKey: privateKeyUint8Array.slice(32), secretKey: privateKeyUint8Array });
  }  
  
  let tweet = Web3.Keypair.generate();
  const balance = await connection.getBalance(author.publicKey);
  console.log('Current balance is', balance / Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, 'SOL');

  // 1 SOL should be enough for almost anything you wanna do
  if (balance / Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL < 3) {
    // You can only get up to 2 SOL per request 
    console.log('Airdropping 1 SOL');
    const airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
      author.publicKey,
      Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );

    const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    await connection.confirmTransaction({
      blockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight,
      signature: airdropSignature,
    });

    const newBalance = await connection.getBalance(author.publicKey);
    console.log('New balance is', newBalance / Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, 'SOL');
  }
  // console.log("New bbaalance is", newBalance / Web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)
  await pingProgram(connection, author, tweet);
}


main()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Finished successfully');
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error:', error.message);
    console.log('Stack trace:', error.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

And this is my anchor code if needed

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::system_program;
use solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult;

declare_id!("FS1yZFS9Vjbv77rqXBk46eGUdTgUXP7esZwKxtQFW8Ku");

#[program]
pub mod solana_twitter {
    use super::*;
    pub fn send_tweet(ctx: Context<SendTweet>, title: String) -> ProgramResult {
        let tweet: &mut Account<Tweet> = &mut ctx.accounts.tweet;
        let author: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.author;
        tweet.title = title.to_string();
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SendTweet<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = author, space = 100)]
    pub tweet: Account<'info, Tweet>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub author: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(address = system_program::ID)]
    pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Tweet {
    pub author: Pubkey,
    pub title: String,
}
```

The Terminal output if needed

```
Using existing keypair
Current balance is 2 SOL
Airdropping 1 SOL
New balance is 4 SOL
Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.
Stack trace: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/test/anchor/sol-tutorial/solana-intro-client/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5791:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/test/anchor/sol-tutorial/solana-intro-client/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5750:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/Users/test/anchor/sol-tutorial/solana-intro-client/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5738:12)
    at async Object.sendAndConfirmTransaction (/Users/test/anchor/sol-tutorial/solana-intro-client/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/utils/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:35:21)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've mixed up your parameters. The function is defined as

```
async function pingProgram(
  connection: Web3.Connection,
  tweet: Web3.Keypair,
  author: Web3.Keypair
) {
```

and you're calling

```
  await pingProgram(connection, author, tweet);
```

So you're trying to pay with the tweet account, which doesn't have any SOL. Change up the params and you should be good to go!

Comment: That did not work. the author is the payer so i changed the await the pingProgram(connection,tweet,author) so the author as the last parameter but we now get this error Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x64
Stack trace: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x64

Comment: Unfortunately, we can only solve one problem at a time! feel free to submit another question